# Continuously receive Data from PC and send control messages via Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, communication

I want to develop an application on my pc which continuously sends sensor data which it receives from a rs232 port to an Android phone via WiFi.

The sensor Data should then be shown on the phone, as soon as it changes.

The phone app should have an UI which shows the sensor data, and also some buttons, to remotely control the pc application.

Since I am new to network programming, what would be the best way to implement the communication between the phone and the pc?

Comment: there are many ways: Bluetooth, network via Wi-Fi, Push Notification, Socket... also, does the communication require checksum / handshake ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many, it depends on the technology and you can choose from Push, sockets, wi-fi... but independently of what it is, I think the best way to implement this is using a `Service`. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). In this case, as the communication will be a long process (probably the whole app life) it's not recommended using an AsyncTask because despite of the common believe, it's intended just for short background processes.